# How to forward an HTTP request with Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim, http-redirect, forward

Is it possible to **forward** a request in Slim?
The meaning of "forward", like in JavaEE, is to **internally redirect** to another route without return the response to the client and maintaining the model.

For example:

```
$app->get('/logout',function () use ($app) {
   //logout code
   $app->view->set("logout",true);
   $app->forward('login'); //no redirect to client please
})->name("logout");

$app->get('/login',function () use ($app) {
   $app->render('login.html');
})->name("login");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to do this would be by using Slim's internal router ([`Slim\Router`](http://dev.slimframework.com/phpdocs/classes/Slim.Router.html)) capabilities and dispatching ([`Slim\Route::dispatch()`](http://dev.slimframework.com/phpdocs/classes/Slim.Route.html#dispatch)) the matched route (meaning: executing the callable from a matched route without any redirect). There are a couple of options that come to mind (depending on your setup):

#### 1. calling a named route + callable doesn't take any arguments (your example)

```
$app->get('/logout',function () use ($app) {
   $app->view->set("logout",true);

   // here comes the magic:
   // getting the named route
   $route = $app->router()->getNamedRoute('login');

   // dispatching the matched route
   $route->dispatch(); 

})->name("logout");
```

This should definitely do the trick for you, but I still want to show the other scenarios ...

---

#### 2. calling a named route + callable with arguments

The above example will fail ... because now we need to pass arguments to the callable

```
   // getting the named route
   $route = $app->router()->getNamedRoute('another_route');

   // calling the function with an argument or array of arguments
   call_user_func($route->getCallable(), 'argument');
```

Dispatching the route (with $route->dispatch()) will invoke all middleware, but here we are just calling the the callable directly ... so to get the full package we should consider the next option ...

---

#### 3. calling any route

Without named routes we can get a route by finding the one matching the a http method and pattern. For this we use [`Router::getMatchedRoutes($httpMethod, $pattern, $reload)`](http://dev.slimframework.com/phpdocs/classes/Slim.Router.html#getMatchedRoutes) with reload set to `TRUE`.

```
   // getting the matched route
   $matched = $app->router()->getMatchedRoutes('GET','/classes/name', true);

   // dispatching the (first) matched route
   $matched[0]->dispatch();
```

Here you might want to add some checks and for example dispatch `notFound` in case no route is matched.
I hope you get the idea =)

Answer (score 1):

There is `redirect()` method. However it sends an `302 Temporary Redirect` response which you do not want.

```
$app->get("/foo", function () use ($app) {
    $app->redirect("/bar");
});
```

Another possibility is `pass()` which tells application to continue to next matching route. When `pass()` is called Slim will immediately stop processing the current matching route and invoke the next matching route.

If no subsequent matching route is found, a `404 Not Found` is sent to the client.

```
$app->get('/hello/foo', function () use ($app) {
    echo "You won't see this...";
    $app->pass();
});

$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) use ($app) {
    echo "But you will see this!";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to redirect them. There is no forward in Slim. But you can set a status code for example in the redirect function. When you redirect to a route you should get that functionality you want.

```
// With route
$app->redirect('login');
// With path and status code
$app->redirect('/foo', 303);
```

here is an example from the documentation:

```
<?php
$authenticateForRole = function ( $role = 'member' ) {
    return function () use ( $role ) {
        $user = User::fetchFromDatabaseSomehow();
        if ( $user->belongsToRole($role) === false ) {
            $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
            $app->flash('error', 'Login required');
            $app->redirect('/login');
        }
    };
};
```